# A series involving factorial

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, factorial

Series from $n=0$ to infinity of $n!/1000^n$

I know the limit of $n!$ is infinity and $1000^n$ is also infinity. In this regard, I really don't see how L'Hopital's rule can work in this case. How do I tackle this problem ?

Comment: Hint:  use [Sterling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Comment: This series diverges by the root test.

Comment: Oh, did you actually mean the series?  I thought you just wanted the limit of the terms.  As others have pointed out, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {n!}{1000^n}$ diverges.

Comment: when $n> 1000, n!$ starts to grow faster than $1000^n$ and will eventually dominate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{(n+1)!}{1000^{n+1}}}{\frac{n!}{1000^n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{1000}=\infty,$$your series diverges, by the ratio test.

Answer (score 0):

For $n >2000$ we have $\frac {n!} {(1000)^{n}} >\frac {(2000)(2001)...n} {(1000)^{n}} >2^{n-2000}$ so the general term of the series tends to $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

When you go from the term $n$ to the term $n+1$, you multiply by $n+1$ and divide by $1000$. So the numerator will eventually "win" and make the terms larger and larger.

---

More rigorously, for $n>1000$,

$$t_n:=\frac{n!}{1000^n}\ge t_{1000}1.001^{n-1000},$$ forming a diverging geometric series.